# Visual Studio Design/Evaluate/Project-Load MSBuild condition

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

The `BuildingInsideVisualStudio` [MSBuild property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/visual-studio-integration-msbuild?view=vs-2015#building-solutions) allows one to write conditions based on whether a certain build is taking place in visual studio:

```
<MyProp Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' ">Foo</MyProp>
```

However that property is not set during evaluation/design/project-load, so for example in a ccproj something like this doesn't work:

```
<Foo Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' ">2.9</Foo>
<ProductVersion>$(Foo)</ProductVersion>
```

Is there a VS evaluation/design/project-load `BuildingInsideVisualStudio` equivalent?

**EDIT**
Repro steps:

1. In Visual Studio 2017, create a new `Azure Cloud Service` project.
2. Close the solution in VS and open the `ccproj` in a text editor and replace the line `<ProductVersion>2.9</ProductVersion>` (you might have a different version) with:

.

```
<Foo Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' ">2.9</Foo>
<Foo Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' ">9.9</Foo>
<ProductVersion>$(Foo)</ProductVersion>
```

3. Open the solution in Visual Studio, you will be greeted with the warning:

> This project is associated with a newer version of the Microsoft Azure
>   Tools. You must download the tools and reload the project to continue.

In other words, during project load, `BuildingInsideVisualStudio` has evaluated to false, and so the unsupported 9.9 `ProductVersion` was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> so for example in a ccproj something like this doesn't work:

Actually it works well on my side, so I guess if the place of the property makes this difference. I tried it in every place it could be, but can't reproduce same issue.

According to your `not set during evaluation/design/project-load`,do you use the property as the project node's condition like this:

```
<Project... Condition="$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) " ...>
      ...
</Project>
```

Only in this situation the property can't work since the Project node itself doesn't support `Condition`. We have to use it `inside <Project>` like using it to a PropertyGroup,ItemGroup,Property...

> Is there a VS evaluation/design/project-load
>   BuildingInsideVisualStudio equivalent?

Not clear about your meaning, but if you mean using the property outside the Project content like below, I'm afraid the answer is negative.

```
<Project Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true'">
   content of project if builds in vs
</Project>

<Project Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'false'">
   content of project if builds not in vs
</Project>
```

If I misunderstand anything please feel free to let me know, more details to reproduce the issue would be expected:)

**Edit:**

With Ohad's details I reproduced the issue.
For now,the `BuildingInsideVisualStudio` property only works when build process starts,it will be set to True only when it **builds** in VS, but not when reloading or opening in VS,which causes the issue.

However i have no idea if there exists a project-load property like: `LoadingInsideVisualStudio`.The answer might be negative.

Comment: Added repro steps to my question - thank you for looking into this :)

Comment: Thanks for your details to help repro it. See my edit.The property can't meet your needs to determine if loading in vs. It's only for build action, not load. However i can't figure out an alternative way to meet your needs:(